# Do Angular shared modules cause additional bundle size?

Tags: angular, module

I'm splitting up my Angular project (currently v7.1.1) into multiple modules to clean up the code. For example `NavbarModule, SideMenuModule, FooterModule`, and they all get loaded into the main `AppModule`. Several of these modules also contain shared modules such as `ButtonsModule, PipesModule`.

Basically I wanted to know if I'm causing additional bundle sizes because I'm sharing assets across multiple modules? Thank you for any information you can share.

Comment: You can answer that yourself by doing comparative builds. Plus,  `webpack-bundle-analyzer` (npm package) could help

Comment: Useful link: https://hackernoon.com/rxjs-reduce-bundle-size-using-lettable-operators-418307295e85